# Compare the time difference between two time servers

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime, batch-file

I'm trying to determine if there is any difference in time between two time servers in Windows. For example, I have time.windows.com and time.nist.gov. Is there a simple way to compare the time difference?

Comment: Could you explain why you would want to do this? Kinda looks like a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From windows you can compare both time sources to your own machine and approximate the difference.

```html
w32tm /monitor /computers:time.windows.com,time.nist.gov
time.windows.com[52.179.17.38:123]:
    ICMP: error IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT - no response in 1000ms
    NTP: -0.0528936s offset from local clock
        RefID: utcnist2.colorado.edu [128.138.141.172]
        Stratum: 2
time.nist.gov[132.163.97.1:123]:
    ICMP: error IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT - no response in 1000ms
    NTP: -0.0476330s offset from local clock
        RefID: 'NIST' [0x5453494E]
        Stratum: 1

Warning:
Reverse name resolution is best effort. It may not be
correct since RefID field in time packets differs across
NTP implementations and may not be using IP addresses.
```

Good Luck!

Shane

Comment: Thank you, this is what I get:

`Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`

`C:\windows\system32>w32tm /monitor /computers:time.windows.com,time.nist.gov
time.windows.com[52.179.17.38:123]:
    ICMP: error IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT - no response in 1000ms
    NTP: error ERROR_TIMEOUT - no response from server in 1000ms
time.nist.gov[129.6.15.27:123]:
    ICMP: error IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT - no response in 1000ms
    NTP: error ERROR_TIMEOUT - no response from server in 1000ms`

Comment: edit: I tried using a different machine and got it to work.